# Regular value, Jacobian determinant of constant sign

Tags: real-analysis, differential-topology

> Why doesn't the Jacobian determinant $Jf$ change sign on $V_x$? Even if $Jf$ is continuous, it is of constant sign on a small neighborbood. How could the following calculation be legitimate? Why can we pull out the $\mathrm{sgn}$ from the inside of the integral? Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function is a diffeomorphism on each such set $V_x$, and so the Jacobian is non-zero (hence of constant sign by connectedness).

Comment: Since $Jf$ is continuous, by taking $\epsilon$ small enough, we can guarantee that $Jf$ is nonzero for all points of $V_x$(Note that $Jf(x)\not= 0$). Am I right? Thank you.

Comment: You haven't included enough of the text to put this in context. Presumably $\Omega$ is compact, so that there are only finitely many preimages of $p$, and then we just take a minimum of a finite number of $\epsilon$’s.

Comment: I am sorry to forget that $\Omega$ is an open bounded set in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: With compact closure? Or $f$ is proper?

Comment: Sorry, Sir. I got to go to school. I want to, if I may, skip your question and confirm one thing. If $Jf$ is nonzero for all points of $V_x$, then $sgn(Jf)$ is a continuous two-valued($\pm 1$) function. By connected-ness of $V_x$,  we then conclude that $sgn(Jf)$ is constant on $V_x$. Am I right? Thank you.

Comment: That's what I said to start with.

Comment: Sir, could you tell me why $$\int_\Omega\cdots=\sum_{x\in f^{-1}(p)}\int_{V_x}\cdots,$$ please? The union of those $V_x$ cannot be $\Omega$.

Comment: Remember how $\Phi$ was constructed. Details!